# Fundamental Groups of Brieskorn Spheres

Tags: algebraic-topology, low-dimensional-topology

I am trying to calculate the fundamental group of the Brieskorn sphere $\Sigma(p,q,r)$. However, I have no clue how to do that. Is there an elementary way to calculate it?

$\Sigma(p,q,r)$ is defined for given positive integers $p,q,r$ in the following way:

Take the polynomial $f(z_1,z_2,z_3)=z_1^p+z_2^q+z_3^r$ defined $\mathbb C^3\to\mathbb C$ with an isolated singularity at the origin $(0,0,0)$. So, the zero set $V_f$ of this polynomial is a 2-dimensional complex manifold, and essentially a 4-manifold, away from the origin. When we (transversally) intersect $V_f$ with some 5-dimensional sphere $S^5_\epsilon\subset \mathbb C^3$ centered at the origin with radius $\epsilon$, we obtain a closed connected orientable 3-manifold. This manifold is denoted $\Sigma(p,q,r)$, and called a Brieskorn sphere, named after Egbert Brieskorn.

Comment: Do you know what Seifert manifolds are ? Brieskorn spheres are special cases.

Comment: Thanks! I know Seifert fibered spaces and formalization of their fundamental groups. I'll try to find a Seifert fibration for the manifold.

Comment: Hint: Seifert bundles (typically) appear from $S^1$-actions on 3-manifolds. Since each Brieskorn singularity is quasi-homogeneous, it supports a $C^*$-action; with a little bit of work, you get an $S^1$-action on the link. Now, you have to identify the quotient (it is a sphere, since this is true for the $C^*$-action) and singular orbits (generically, three circles). I guess, this is what Milnor did in his paper.

Comment: @MoisheCohen Do you mean action $e^{it}:(x,y,z)\to(e^{\frac{it}{p}}x,e^{\frac{it}{q}}y,e^{\frac{it}{r}}z)$ ? How do you know that quotient is sphere ? Milnor distinguish three cases depending whether $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}+\frac{1}{r}-1$ is positive (spherical), negative (hyperbolic) or zero (nilpotent).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all done in Milnor's paper on the subject : http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/milnbries.pdf